# How to light an object consistently? Like a matcap

Tags: lighting

I’m attempting to make a turntable animation of a toy-like object. The video will have a transparent background. I’ve tried studio lighting set up, but without great result. I am looking for a lighting setup like how the matcap looks.

Comment: You could use the Workbench render engine and set the lighting to MatCap? It's also possible to create a MatCap shader in cycles but that would probably only get you the same result but slower.

Comment: @kay combobulate as KacperYZ asked - some reference image of desire result would help to offer something otherwise Jackdaw is right - I was in process of writing, sorry here

Answer (score 1):

Matcap Material

[image]

Matcap Material + Your Texture (here as UV_Grid)

[image]

Workbench

[image]

Both examples here...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide some screen shots?
I think about creating great uv sphere that could surround your scene (somethink like hdr but with consistant light) You could do that by applying emision material to uv sphere